# How do perform a delete on listview that's not bound by a control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView and I have set up my Delete Link button.  When I clicked Delete however I get `"The ListView 'ListView' raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled."` So I decided to try and implement the `DeleteLinkButton_Click()` and `ListView_ItemDeleted()` ... however I can't figure out how to identify which row I've selected for my `DeleteLinkButton_Click()`.

I didn't bind my source through a control instead I used the following method.

```
ListView.DataSource = myObject.RetreiveInfo()
ListView.DataBind()
```

I figure if I can identify my row I can access the values of the labels there and pass them to a stored procedure and perform my DELETE.

Can anyone help?  If I need to provide more code just let me know!

Edit:

**CodeBehind**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Not IsPostBack Then
      UpdateDisplay()
   End If
End Sub

Protected Sub UpdateDistplay()
    ListView.DataSource = myObject.RetrieveInfo()
    ListView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**ASPX Page**

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteLinkButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this Info?')" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      <td>
         <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can get a better picture of whats' going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the index of the item being deleted in the [ItemDeleting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdeleting.aspx) event, so handling that first might help you out a bit more.  It looks like this:

```
Protected Sub myListView_OnItemDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim deletedIndex As Integer
    deletedIndex = e.ItemIndex
End Sub
```

At this point, you now have the index of the item whose delete button was clicked, so you can look up the label and perform the `DELETE` (as you mentioned in your question).

Good luck!

Comment: @daveomcd thanks for the edit.  My vb.net is rusty at best =)

Answer (score 3):

**In page design put this delete button in .**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnDelete" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ID") %>'
                                OnClick="lbtnDelete_Click" CssClass="deleteButton" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
                                    <img src="resources/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

**On page behind write this code**

```
protected void lbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
        Tbl_Mode Tbl_Mode = DataClassesDataContext.Tbl_Modes.Single(p => p.ID == ID);
        DataClassesDataContext.Tbl_Modes.DeleteOnSubmit(Tbl_Mode);
        DataClassesDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        divDelete.Visible = true;
        Bind();
    }
```